# ¿Traer checkeado desde base de datos radio button dinamico?

Tags: php, jquery, json, codeigniter

Tengo este radio button que se llena desde la base de datos dianamicamente, 
¿De que forma podría traer checkeado desde la base de datos su valor para editarlo? , 
me serviria ya sea en jquery o php saludos gracias !

```
<div class="inline-group">   
<?php foreach ($Ubicacion as $key => $value) { ?>
<label class="radio">    
    <input id="<?= $value->nombre?>" type="radio" class="radio" value="<?= $value->id_ubicacion?>" name="ubicacion"/><?= $value->nombre?>
    <i>
    </i>
    </input>
</label>
<?php } ?>
 </div>
```

Este dato es una clave foránea , al llamar al array $Ubicacion me rellena el foreach con los datos de ese array , en otro array tengo los datos que estan almacenados, de que forma dentro de ese foreach puedo comparar el id del radio button con el id del array en mi base de datos para traer el dato checkeado?

Comment: Hola Javier, Lo que entiendo que deseas es que: Si ya esta Checked entonces quieres que se ponga el input Radio en tipo Checked no? . entonces es necesario saber como guardar el valor checked en la base de datos?, lo puedes hacer mediante el value, si el value es distinto de null, etc. o bien explicate mejor pleaseee

Comment: En tu código falta saber qué ID es el que está chequeado.

Answer (score 1):

si desde la base de datos tienes el campo "esta_checkeado", compara si esta en true y lo imprimes en medio del input (para que un radio quede checkeado debe tener el atributo checked). Ojala te sirva, saludos.

```
<?= $value->esta_checkeado == true ? "checked" : "" ?>
```

quedaria asi:

```
<div class="inline-group">   
<?php foreach ($Ubicacion as $key => $value) { ?>
<label class="radio">    
    <input id="<?= $value->nombre?>" <?= $value->esta_checkeado == true ? "checked":""=> type="radio" class="radio" value="<?= $value->id_ubicacion?>" name="ubicacion"/><?= $value->nombre?>
    <i>
    </i>
    </input>
</label>
<?php } ?>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero lo siguiente:

```
// Pasar los IDs seleccionados a un array
$IdSeleccionados=array();

foreach ($Seleccionados as $key => $value) {
   $IdSeleccionados[]=$value->ID; // "ID" es el dato a comparar con $value->id_ubicacion
}
```

Entonces:

```
<div class="inline-group">   
<?php foreach ($Ubicacion as $key => $value) { ?>
<label class="radio">    
    <input id="<?= $value->nombre?>" type="radio" class="radio" value="<?= $value->id_ubicacion?>" name="ubicacion" <?= in_array($value->id_ubicacion, $IdSeleccionados)? ' checked="checked" ':'' ?>  /><?= $value->nombre?>
    <i>
    </i>
    </input>
</label>
<?php } ?>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa la propuedad checked `<?php ($value->id_ubicacion === $ubicacion->id_ubicacion) ? 'checked' : ''?>/><?= $value->nombre?> />`:

```
<div class="inline-group">   
<?php foreach ($Ubicacion as $key => $value) : ?>
<label class="radio">    
    <input id="<?= $value->nombre?>"
           type="radio"
           class="radio"
           value="<?= $value->id_ubicacion?>"
           name="ubicacion" 
           <?php echo ($value->id_ubicacion === $ubicacion->id_ubicacion) ? 'checked' : ''?>/><?= $value->nombre?> />
    <i>
    </i>
    </input>
</label>
<?php endforeach; ?>
 </div>
```